# Charset wrong after submitting form and also not correctly inserted into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, forms, character-encoding

I have a little form in my script where my (german) users should enter some text.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
....
<body>

<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php
                                echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                            ?>
">

....

</form>
...
<h3>Möchten Sie noch....?</h3>
<p>Hier können Sie dies das...
    Es heißt, man soll....
</p>
```

The text is ok when you enter the page the first time. But after submitting the form, the charset is wrong. All the 'Ö', 'ä', 'ß' etc. will not be displayed correctly anymore.
I also tried `ISO-8859-15` but it had no effect.

The same problem occurs in the MYSQL Database. The letters are not inserted correctly, though the collotation is `utf8_general_ci`.

The query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` returns:

```
Variable_name               Value   
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8
character_sets_dir          /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Comment: This might be more relevant to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

There might be few others things impacting this, as setting collation is usually not enough:

- Your connection is not using UTF-8 by default. Please add this after connecting to MySQL (before doing any inserts):

  ```
  query("SET NAMES utf8");
  ```

  Now check your data, if new rows are correct, then just add this after mysql connect function.
- Your data is not stored as UTF-8 in the server. To check this, run this query:

  ```
  show variables like 'char%';
  ```

  This should return only `utf8` (with exception of filesystem usually being `binary`). If it does not, then your MySQL server is not fully configured for UTF-8 support.

**Update**

To set your MySQL server to full UTF-8 support, edit `my.cnf` file (usually in `/etc/mysql`) and add these:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

After changing these, restart your MySQL server, connect to MySQL and perform these operations (change database to name of your database):

```
use database;
set character_set_database=utf8;
set character_set_server=utf8;
```

Comment: ok, thanx. I edited my answer. So one problem is with my MySQL server. But why are umlauts not displayed correctly in a with a <p>?

Comment: because the data you store is double encoded. Your server is actually storing it as UTF-8 converted latin. I have updated my answer on how to update the Server/Database configuration.